# Add a line to each address in each of the three columns

Tags: ruby, unix, text, sed

I need to add a certain line on top of each of the addresses which are in a text file in following format:

```
g51/b18468 Postgg On 30/05/2013      N51/b39897 Postgg On 30/05/2013      LR51/b23428 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Rgv. XXXXX                           Mr. bBnMbNNbN.M                      Bro. bBRbgbM .S,
KbgbNg bSSgMBLY Og gOg,              LOT 92, KbMPUNg                      gRbgg gOMMUNnTY ggNTRg,
52, gLN. TnMUR,                      BbTU 4, 43950                        4, LORONg SS 23/6g,
POST BOX 20, 43007 KbgbNg            SUNgbn PgLnK                         47400 PgTbLnNg gbYb,
MbLbYSnb                             SgLbNgUR                             SgLbNgOR, W.MbLbYSnb
                                     MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb


ML51/b13179 Postgg On 30/05/2013     W51/b41363 Postgg On 30/05/2013      Lg51/b29053 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Bro. bBRbgbM .V                      Bro. bLbPPbN                         Pbstor. bLgRgg PRbgbSbM
NO:18,PgRSnbRbN                      NO.60, LORONg SgRbn PgRMbn 9,        1-2-2, MggbN nNTbN bPbRTMgNT,
RnSgbg .7                            TbMbN SgRbn PgRMbn,                  gbLbN 1/21g Ogg gbLbN gOMBbK
TbMbN RnSgbg                         34300, BbTbN SgRbn,                  53000 KUbLb LUMPUR
30100 nPOg, PgRbK                    PgRbK                                MbLbYSnb
MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb


LR510b13172 Postgg On 30/05/2013     ML51/b9877 Postgg On 30/05/2013      LR51/b9905 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Sns. bLLbMbg (b) NgSbM               Bro. bLVnN bNbNg .b                  Mrs. bNnTgb VngTOR
NO:44,gbLbN gbMbn                    NO:3,gbLbN TgRbTbn 3                 7,gbLbN PbRn
TbMbN TbPbg gbYb                     TbMbN SbRn,TgRbTbn                   PbRn gbRggNS
35000 TbPbg                          44000 KUbLb KUBU BgbRU               nPOg,30100
PgRbK,                               SgLbNgOR                             PgRbK
MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb


ML51/b13180 Postgg On 30/05/2013     ML51/b13203 Postgg On 30/05/2013     g51/b9942 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Bro. bNTONY                          Bro. bNTONYSWbMY                     Pbstor. bROKnbNbTgbN
NO:399,LORONg KgNbVn 3/2b            LbgbNg gUSUN gURnbM                  NO:M4 g/7
TbMbN KgNbRn                         42700 BbNTnNg                        gbLbN PbNgbN nNgbg 4/1b
09000 KULnM                          SgLbNgOR g.g                         PbNgbN nNgbg
Kggbg                                MbLbYSnb                             55100,KUbLb LUMPUR
MbLbYSnb                                                                  MbLbYSnb
```

I have scrambled the letters for safety and privacy. What I want is that each address should be line this:

```
My New Line                          My New Line                          My New Line
g51/b18468 Postgg On 30/05/2013      N51/b39897 Postgg On 30/05/2013      LR51/b23428 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Rgv. XXXXX                           Mr. bBnMbNNbN.M                      Bro. bBRbgbM .S,
KbgbNg bSSgMBLY Og gOg,              LOT 92, KbMPUNg                      gRbgg gOMMUNnTY ggNTRg,
52, gLN. TnMUR,                      BbTU 4, 43950                        4, LORONg SS 23/6g,
POST BOX 20, 43007 KbgbNg            SUNgbn PgLnK                         47400 PgTbLnNg gbYb,
MbLbYSnb                             SgLbNgUR                             SgLbNgOR, W.MbLbYSnb
                                     MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb
```

I dont know how to do this.  There is no delimiter here to mark start and end.

Comment: The columns are fixed so you basically have to insert a static line every 10 lines.

Comment: Pleading for help isn't necessary. If people can help they will if you've written your question so it supplies the information needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it in Ruby:

```
INPUT_FILE = 'test.txt'
OUTPUT_FILE = INPUT_FILE + '.new'
COLUMN_WIDTH = 37

File.open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') do |fo|
  # read using paragraph mode
  File.foreach(INPUT_FILE, '') do |paragraph_in|

    addr1_new_line = "My New Line"
    addr2_new_line = addr1_new_line
    addr3_new_line = addr1_new_line

    column1_new_line, column2_new_line, column3_new_line = [
      addr1_new_line,
      addr2_new_line,
      addr3_new_line
    ].map{ |nl|
      nl + (' ' * (COLUMN_WIDTH - nl.length))
    }

    fo.puts column1_new_line + column2_new_line + column3_new_line + "\n"
    fo.puts paragraph_in
  end
end
```

With sample output:

```
My New Line                          My New Line                          My New Line
g51/b18468 Postgg On 30/05/2013      N51/b39897 Postgg On 30/05/2013      LR51/b23428 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Rgv. XXXXX                           Mr. bBnMbNNbN.M                      Bro. bBRbgbM .S,
KbgbNg bSSgMBLY Og gOg,              LOT 92, KbMPUNg                      gRbgg gOMMUNnTY ggNTRg,
52, gLN. TnMUR,                      BbTU 4, 43950                        4, LORONg SS 23/6g,
POST BOX 20, 43007 KbgbNg            SUNgbn PgLnK                         47400 PgTbLnNg gbYb,
MbLbYSnb                             SgLbNgUR                             SgLbNgOR, W.MbLbYSnb
                                     MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb

My New Line                          My New Line                          My New Line
ML51/b13179 Postgg On 30/05/2013     W51/b41363 Postgg On 30/05/2013      Lg51/b29053 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Bro. bBRbgbM .V                      Bro. bLbPPbN                         Pbstor. bLgRgg PRbgbSbM
NO:18,PgRSnbRbN                      NO.60, LORONg SgRbn PgRMbn 9,        1-2-2, MggbN nNTbN bPbRTMgNT,
RnSgbg .7                            TbMbN SgRbn PgRMbn,                  gbLbN 1/21g Ogg gbLbN gOMBbK
TbMbN RnSgbg                         34300, BbTbN SgRbn,                  53000 KUbLb LUMPUR
30100 nPOg, PgRbK                    PgRbK                                MbLbYSnb
MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb

My New Line                          My New Line                          My New Line
LR510b13172 Postgg On 30/05/2013     ML51/b9877 Postgg On 30/05/2013      LR51/b9905 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Sns. bLLbMbg (b) NgSbM               Bro. bLVnN bNbNg .b                  Mrs. bNnTgb VngTOR
NO:44,gbLbN gbMbn                    NO:3,gbLbN TgRbTbn 3                 7,gbLbN PbRn
TbMbN TbPbg gbYb                     TbMbN SbRn,TgRbTbn                   PbRn gbRggNS
35000 TbPbg                          44000 KUbLb KUBU BgbRU               nPOg,30100
PgRbK,                               SgLbNgOR                             PgRbK
MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb                             MbLbYSnb

My New Line                          My New Line                          My New Line
ML51/b13180 Postgg On 30/05/2013     ML51/b13203 Postgg On 30/05/2013     g51/b9942 Postgg On 30/05/2013
Bro. bNTONY                          Bro. bNTONYSWbMY                     Pbstor. bROKnbNbTgbN
NO:399,LORONg KgNbVn 3/2b            LbgbNg gUSUN gURnbM                  NO:M4 g/7
TbMbN KgNbRn                         42700 BbNTnNg                        gbLbN PbNgbN nNgbg 4/1b
09000 KULnM                          SgLbNgOR g.g                         PbNgbN nNgbg
Kggbg                                MbLbYSnb                             55100,KUbLb LUMPUR
MbLbYSnb                                                                  MbLbYSnb
```

The trick is to put Ruby into "paragraph" mode when reading lines. Many of the IO and File methods have a concept of a line separator, AKA the magic `$/` variable. By passing in different values Ruby will read or write text files differently. In this case, by passing in an empty string it will read in "paragraph" mode, meaning a "line" is read until two successive "\n" are found. In most text "\n\n" marks a new paragraph.

The side-effect of this is that *we don't need to care or know*, how many lines make up a paragraph, because Ruby is going to read until it finds "\n\n", automatically doing the right thing. We only care that Ruby said it found another paragraph.

Once Ruby's read a paragraph it's a pretty simple task to create the new line to be output, determine the column widths, and output the new line followed by the previously read paragraph.

I allowed for there to be a different heading for each line and column. You can adjust the `addr1_new_line`, `addr2_new_line` and `addr3_new_line` values as necessary. The code will automatically adjust column widths as necessary to keep them aligned, as long as they're shorter than the column width.

Answer (score 1):

Fill up the array `lines`, one way or another, with the lines from your address file, then:

```
new_line = 'My New Line                          My New Line                          My New Line'
lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
  if index.zero? or lines[index-1].blank?
    puts new_line
  end
  puts line
end
```

You can replace the `puts` with an output to a file, an array, etc., as needed.

Answer (score 1):

To add a line ahead of each record, put your tool into paragraph mode first. This is often done by setting a null record separator. Then just print your line before you print the record. Here's how you could do this using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print (NR > 1 ? "\n\n" : "") "NEW\t\tNEW\t\tNEW" ORS $0 }' RS= file
```

Since your columns are fixed-width, you will need to adjust the amount of whitespace to neaten things up. I'll leave that for you. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way (assuming input text in `addr` and it has fixed amount of lines in each paragraph):

```
str = "My New Line                          My New Line                          My New Line\n"
new_addr = addr.lines.each_slice(9).map{|el| str + el.join}
```